# Reusable input component for other forms in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-dropzone

I just got an independent component. It's a dropzone field that we are using to get user files. This dropzone component is a form with its own `onsubmit` event.

We are doing some refactoring in the app and there are scenarios in which we need to reuse this dropzone component in other forms that have other kinds of fields, such as radio buttons or maybe text fields. Since my dropzone has its own onsubmit event and its own parent form label, I obviously cannot reuse it in another form. I cannot add a form inside a form, so I'm trying to find the best way to make a single dropzone field that can be reused inside any existing form with other fields.

The little issue is that my component already has its own `onsubmit` event that uses the `createFile` hook to upload files to the server when the submit button is pressed, so I don't know how to make another dropzone component that can be added to any existing form and will automatically upload the files that are dropped inside the component to the server.

This is the component:

```
import 'twin.macro';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';

import { createFile } from '@api/file';
import { ALLOWED_MIMES } from '@utility/constants';
import prettyBytes from '@utility/prettyBytes';
import Button from '@components/Button';
import ErrorFallback from '@components/ErrorFallback';
import type { User } from '@types';
import PreparedFiles from './PreparedFiles';
import UploadIcon from './UploadIcon';

const SingleDropzone: React.FC<{
  user: User;
  slug?: string;
  uploadComplete?: () => void;
}> = ({ user, slug, uploadComplete }) => {
  const [queuedFiles, setQueuedFiles] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

  const onDrop = (acceptedFiles: File[]) => setQueuedFiles(acceptedFiles);

  const resetQueuedFiles = () => setQueuedFiles([]);

  const onSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const promises = queuedFiles.map((file: File) => {
      setUploading(true);

      return createFile({
        user_id: user.id,
        name: file.name,
        upload: file,
        // will use the slug or the default folder
        folder_slug: slug || null,
      });
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(resetQueuedFiles)
      .catch((error) => {
        // trigger error boundary
        throw new Error(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setUploading(false);
        if (uploadComplete) {
          uploadComplete();
        }
      });

    return false;
  };

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
      <form
        encType="multipart/form-data"
        method="post"
        action="/api/files"
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {queuedFiles.length > 0 ? (
          <PreparedFiles files={queuedFiles} />
        ) : (
          <Dropzone accept={ALLOWED_MIMES} onDrop={onDrop}>
            {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
              <section tw="flex items-center justify-center rounded border-2 border-dashed my-5">
                <div
                  tw="flex flex-col items-center space-y-2 w-full p-5"
                  {...getRootProps()}
                >
                  <input {...getInputProps()} />
                  <div tw="w-9 h-9">
                    <UploadIcon />
                  </div>
                  <p tw="type-1450 text-gray-600">
                    <span tw="text-indigo-600">Upload a file</span> or drag and
                    drop
                  </p>
                  <p tw="type-1240 text-gray-500">
                    PNG, JPG, PDF, Doc up to 20MB
                  </p>
                </div>
              </section>
            )}
          </Dropzone>
        )}
        {queuedFiles.length > 0 ? (
          <div tw="mt-5 w-full flex items-center justify-end space-x-3">
            {uploading ? null : (
              <Button
                type="button"
                styleType="none"
                tw="underline"
                onClick={resetQueuedFiles}
              >
                Cancel
              </Button>
            )}
            {uploading ? (
              <Button type="button" styleType="primary" tw="opacity-70">
                Uploading...
              </Button>
            ) : (
              <Button type="submit" styleType="primary">
                Upload
              </Button>
            )}
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </form>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};

export default SingleDropzone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% if you understood you correctly. But if you have a already existing component that you wanna be able to reuse with different values, i would look into props. Should be rather simple.